# How to make scapy UI in color

Tags: scapy

How can I make scapy be colored, like this:
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1c/Windows_scapy_screenshot.png

When I am trying to edit the color theme with the following commad:

conf.color_theme = ColorOnBlackTheme()

It makes everything gibberish:

http://prntscr.com/ntcdq2

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#customizing-the-terminal

1- Make sure you're using the latest version (or try the [github version](https://github.com/secdev/scapy))

2- Make sure you have IPython Installed

Comment: No, I don't have Ipython installed. That is probably the problem. Thanks!